# Error with .Net is not correctly deserializing

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization

I have the following class:

```
public class MyData
{
    public Data2[] Data2 { get; set; }
}

public class Data2
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

In my appsettings.json, I have this:

```
{
    "Data": [
       {
           "X": "1",
           "Y": "2",
       },
       {
           "X": "4",
           "Y": "5",
       }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize this in startup.cs:

```
var data = Configuration.GetSection("Data").Get<MyData>();
```

The problem that I have is that `data.Data2` is null.

Comment: So your `Data` in config is not `MyData` by directly `Data2` array ... you don't have `Data2` string in your config at all so what is you expected

Comment: Not seeing `Data2` anywhere in the JSON would certainly make me wonder if everything is set up right here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's correct - `Data2` does not feature in the JSON.  So what would the class have to look like in order for this to deserialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is wrong. You need to use classes like this:

```
public class Datum    {
    public string X { get; set; } 
    public string Y { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; } 
}
```

You can use this [website](https://json2csharp.com/) to convert any JSON to a valid C# class.

Answer (score 1):

try:

From:

```
public Data2[] Data2 { get; set; }
```

To:

```
public Data2[] Data { get; set; }
```